# Trying to run a Random Forest Model in Jupyter but I can't seem to find where the problem is

Tags: random-forest

This is the code I use. This code only gives me 0's as output for my y_pred which instead it should be giving me 0 and 1.

```
class DecisionTree:
    def __init__(self, max_depth=None, max_features=None):
        self.max_depth = max_depth
        self.max_features = max_features

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.tree = self._build_tree(X, y, depth=0)
        print(f'Tree classes: {np.unique(self.predict(X))}')


    def _build_tree(self, X, y, depth):
        if self.max_depth is not None and depth == self.max_depth:
            return np.bincount(y).argmax()

        if self.max_features is not None:
            feature_indices = np.random.choice(X.shape[1], self.max_features, replace=False)
            X_subset = X[:, feature_indices]
        else:
            X_subset = X

        feature_index = np.argmax(np.abs(np.median(X_subset, axis=0) - 0.5))
        threshold = 0.5

        left_mask = X[:, feature_index] <= threshold
        right_mask = ~left_mask

        if not any(left_mask) or not any(right_mask):
            return np.bincount(y).argmax()

        left_tree = self._build_tree(X[left_mask], y[left_mask], depth + 1)
        right_tree = self._build_tree(X[right_mask], y[right_mask], depth + 1)

        return (feature_index, threshold, left_tree, right_tree)

    def predict(self, X):
        return self._predict_tree(self.tree, X)

    def _predict_tree(self, node, X):
        if isinstance(node, tuple):
            feature_index, threshold, left_tree, right_tree = node
            mask = X[:, feature_index] <= threshold
            predictions = np.zeros(len(X))  # Initialize with zeros
            predictions[mask] = self._predict_tree(left_tree, X[mask])
            predictions[~mask] = self._predict_tree(right_tree, X[~mask])
            return predictions
        else:
            return np.full(len(X), int(node))



class RandomForest:
    def __init__(self, n_estimators=100, max_depth=None, max_features=None):
        self.n_estimators = n_estimators
        self.max_depth = max_depth
        self.max_features = max_features
        self.forest = []

    def fit(self, X, y):
        for _ in range(self.n_estimators):
            tree = DecisionTree(max_depth=self.max_depth, max_features=self.max_features)
            tree_indices = np.random.choice(X.shape[1], self.max_features, replace=False)
            tree.fit(X[:, tree_indices], y)
            self.forest.append(tree)
            print(f'Tree {_ + 1} classes: {np.unique(tree.predict(X[:, tree_indices]))}')

    def predict(self, X):
        predictions = [tree.predict(X) for tree in self.forest]
        # Ensure consistent shapes by converting lists of arrays to a 2D array
        predictions_array = np.vstack(predictions).T
        return np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: int(np.bincount(x).argmax()), axis=1, arr=predictions_array)

    """        
    def predict(self, X):
        predictions = np.array([tree.predict(X) for tree in self.forest]).T
        return np.array([int(np.median(np.bincount(row))) for row in predictions])
    """
    """
    def predict(self, X):
        predictions = np.array([tree.predict(X) for tree in self.forest]).T
        #return np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: int(np.median(np.bincount(x))), axis=1, arr=predictions)

        #return np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: int(np.bincount(x).argmax()), axis=1, arr=predictions)
        return np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: self.break_ties(x), axis=1, arr=predictions)
        
    def break_ties(self, row):
        counts = np.bincount(row)
        max_count = np.max(counts)
        candidates = np.where(counts == max_count)[0]
        return np.random.choice(candidates)
    """   
#Create a random forest
forest = RandomForest(n_estimators=10, max_depth=3, max_features=None)

#Fit the random forest
forest.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Make predictions using the random forest
y_pred = forest.predict(X_test)

#Print accuracy
accuracy = np.mean(y_pred == y_test)
print(f'The accuracy of the random forest: {accuracy}')
print("Prediction values: ", np.unique(y_pred))
```

In the predict class, I think its throwing me a 2D array instead of a 1D array. The other error that gives me is: "too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed